# como puedo hacer para obtener el valor del IPC desde la pagina del SII de Chile y mostrarlo en una pagina web

Tags: javascript, html, css

Agradeceria su asistencia en como puedo hacer para obtener el valor del IPC desde la pagina del SII de Chile y mostrarlo en una pagina web, tengo este codigo base, pero no se como obtener y mostrar los valores pedidos

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="IPC.css">
    <title>IPC monthly values from SII</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="ipc-values-container"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      let apiUrl = 'https://www.sii.cl/api/ipc/values/2022';
      $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          if(data.status == 'OK') {
            let output = '<ul>';
            data.values.forEach((value) => {
              output += `<li>Month: ${value.month}, Value: ${value.value}</li>`
            });
            output += '</ul>'
            $('.ipc-values-container').append(output);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

la pagina desde donde se obtienen los valores que necesito es esta https://www.sii.cl/valores_y_fechas/utm/utm2022.htm

de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Pero esa es una pagina o una API?

Answer (score 0):

Esta página no existe -> https://www.sii.cl/api/ipc/values/2022

Pero puedes obtener los valores directamente desde esta otra https://www.sii.cl/valores_y_fechas/utm/utm2022.htm

Para esto debes saltarte el problema del CORS usando proxy como por ejemplo https://allorigins.win/

```js
let apiUrl = `https://api.allorigins.win/get?url=${encodeURIComponent('https://www.sii.cl/valores_y_fechas/utm/utm2022.htm')}`;

$('.ipc-values-container').load(apiUrl + " #table_export");
```

```css
table{
  font-size:10px
}
th{
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    background: #ededed;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ipc-values-container"></div>
```

O si solo quieres los datos del IPC, tal como lo tienes en tu código sería lo siguiente

```js
let apiUrl = `https://api.allorigins.win/get?url=${encodeURIComponent('https://www.sii.cl/valores_y_fechas/utm/utm2022.htm')}`;

$.ajax({
  url: apiUrl,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    let output = '<ul>';
   $(data.contents).find("#table_export").find("tbody tr").each(function(e,fila){
      let celdas = $(fila).find("td,th");
      let mes = celdas[0].innerText;
      let ipc = celdas[3].innerText;
      output += `<li>Month: ${mes}, Value: ${ipc}</li>`;
     
   });
     output += '</ul>';
     $('.ipc-values-container').append(output);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ipc-values-container"></div>
```